# Want to break text in input button

Tags: html

Please find the below link, and open this from Firefox browser

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_button

instead of

`value="Click me"`

replace the word with below line.

```
value="I want to break this sentence and make it fix width size like 400px and height should be auto."
```

Need to break this button with 400px width and height should be auto as per how long sentence we have.

My existing code is

```
<input type="button" style="display: none; background: none!important; border: none;
                            padding: 0!important; 
 border-bottom: 1px solid #444; cursor: pointer; max-width: 400px; word-wrap: break-word;" onclick="openDrugsPopup(this);"
                            id="lnkdrg2" name="lnkdrg2" value="Drug 2" />
```

Comment: We need to know what you've tried, for one.

Comment: Use a [`textarea`](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/textarea.html).

Comment: <input type="button" style="display: none; background: none!important; border: none;
                                padding: 0!important; /*border is optional*/  
     border-bottom: 1px solid #444; cursor: pointer; max-width: 400px; max-height:400px; word-wrap: break-word;" onclick="openDrugsPopup(this);"
                                id="lnkdrg2" name="lnkdrg2" value="Drug 2" />

Answer (score 3):

Use  instead of  and give width to that button the height increases accordingly the text increases

```
    <button style="width:100px">
     I want to break this sentence and make it fix widht size like 400px
      and height should 
      be auto. any one can help to resolve this issue asap.
     </button>
```

This Works fine in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function msg()
            {
                alert("Hello world!");
            }
        </script>
    </head>
<body>

    <form>
        <input type="button" value="I want to break this sentence and make it fix widht size like 400px and height should be auto. any one can help to resolve this issue asap."     onclick="msg()" style="width=400px; height=auto;">
    </form>

    <p>The button above activates a JavaScript when it is clicked.</p>

</body>
</html>
```